# Handling TimeSpan in LINQ where TimeSpan is first referenced in query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I understand that LINQ cannot use TimeSpan, however I want to do a where condition on a DateTime with an added TimeSpan. My Issue is however that the TimeSpan is first referenced within the query. I have tried doing it in memory but that also causes issues.

entiteis is of type:

```
System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<CharterRequestDTO>
```

And biddingToCloseIn is defined as:

```
[NotMapped]
public TimeSpan BiddingToCloseIn
{
    get { return TimeSpan.FromTicks(BiddingToCloseInTicks); }
    set { BiddingToCloseInTicks = value.Ticks; }
}
```

Normal:

```
var charterRequestDtoIds = 
    (from e in entities
      where e.ClientId == clientId  
      && e.Status != TrackingState.Void
      && DateTime.Now < e.CreatedAt.AddDays(30).Add(e.BiddingToCloseIn) 
    select e.Id);
```

In Memory:

```
var charterRequestDtoIds = 
  from e in entities.Where( e => e.ClientId == clientId  
   && e.Status != TrackingState.Void
   && DateTime.Now < e.CreatedAt.AddDays(30).Add(e.BiddingToCloseIn) )
  select e.Id;
```

Error for both:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.DateTime Add(System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: How varied is the value for BiddingToCloseIn?  Is it the number of days left? Hours, etc?

Comment: Is `BiddingToCloseIn` a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Yes bidding is an timeSpan, but is assigned in a weird way. Will update the question for you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a `TimeSpan`, add milliseconds (or seconds, minutes, according to the precision you need.)

```
AddDays(30).AddMilliseconds(e.BiddingToCloseIn.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Comment: Hi thank you this worked. Although for anyone reading this answer in the future this can only be done with the in-memory method since SQL does not recognise addDays